# How do I fix this error in VS 2005? "The project file cannot be loaded. The application for project ... is not installed"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How do I fix this error in Visual Studio?

"The project file cannot be loaded. The application for project ... is not installed"

I have copied a whole project onto my PC, both into My Documents/Visual Studio and into inetpub/wwwroot, but when I try to open the project in Visual Studio, it tries to open just 1 file .vssproj and gives me error messages, like : "The project file cannot be loaded. The application for project ... is not installed.". What am I doing wrong?

The VS edition is 2005 as are all the projects aI am trying to load.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specifc? What type of projet are you trying to load? What .NET version? what visual Studio version?

Comment: Please provide more information, help us to help you :)

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the above question with the extra info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it a web application project rather than a website and you haven't upgraded to Service Pack 1 you'll  get this error.

Comment: thanx a million Dean! regards Greg

Comment: What a guess... With such an info provided. Quite amazing. Got to upvote. ^^

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you got no support for particular project type (for example - when trying to open MS MVC web app project without installed MS MVC).

Comment: The projects do not have/use MVC.

Comment: That was an example. You haven't provided project type - i can't tell you what exactly you need to open it. Instead of MVC i could use Database project and VS Development edition (it doesn't support database project as far as i know) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much info, but at a guess I'd say that either you don't have a new enough version of visual studio installed, or when you installed visual studio you didn't install the vb.net language as part of it.  Might have happened due to installing visual studio with SQL Server Express?